# Hive. Select data for the last N weeks

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

I am rewriting some MySQL query into HiveQL and there is something that I wasn't able to nail for some time.

MySQL syntax goes like this (`bc_date` is a *date*) :

```
WHERE date_format(bc_date, '%x-%v') >= date_format(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 16 WEEK, '%x-%v')
```

How does one express that in HiveQL?

My version of Hive doesn't support the `date_format` function, which is available *"as of Hive 1.2.0"*

Comment: which hive version do you use?

Comment: My Hive version is 1.0.0

Comment: is it mandatory to use the `date` type? I mean could you change the type to string?

Comment: That is what i am trying right now :) Answering your question - no it is not mandatory, as long as it gets the job done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a suggestion I have and it seems to work. I am adding 0 to the weeks that are less than 10, for the correct string comparison

```
concat(year(broadcast_time), '-', case when weekofyear(broadcast_time)<10 then concat(0,weekofyear(broadcast_time)) else weekofyear(broadcast_time) end ) >=
concat( year(date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())),112)), '-', case when weekofyear(date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())),112))<10 then concat(0,weekofyear(date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())),112))) else weekofyear(date_sub(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())),112))  end )
```